# How to create Google App Engine Flexible Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tools

I have Eclipse and IntelliJ running side-by-side. 
I have installed and configured Google Cloud Tools on both of them.

IntelliJ gives me the options to deploy my application to Standard and Flexible App Engine environments. Instructions - https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-flex

Eclipse, on the other hand, only allows me to build and deploy App engine apps to Standard App egnine environment. Instructions - https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploying

Is there someway to build an App engine project in Eclipse and deploy it to Flexible App engine environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is under development.  You should be able to use the [Maven plugins](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven) with M2Eclipse in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend just using your IDE as a text editor for flexible app engine projects.  Get familiar with the gcloud command line tool - it's actually pretty amazing.  This will give you much more control over your test environment.